# String comparison in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string

I have 2 strings in a SQL Server 2008 stored proc.

First string is, '2 piece Leather Sofa Sofa'

Second string is '3 pc Sofa'.

If any substring in the second string is present in the first string more than once I need to remove those occurrences from the first string.

For example, in the second string I have Sofa and in the first string I have Sofa twice, I need to remove from the first string any repeated occurrences of word Sofa. How should I do that. I help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I would upvote @marc_s if that were an answer. SQL has pretty poor string manipulation options.

Comment: Silly game where you win only if you don't play !

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server and T-SQL doesn't excel at string manipulations like this. The T-SQL string stuff is quite basic - grab a substring, search for a character and that's about it.

This task is more of a .NET domain.

Can you create a SQL-CLR assembly to handle this and deploy it into SQL Server? That would be by far the easiest way to go...